# Cassandra: Generate a unique ID?

Tags: cassandra, uuid, cql, cql3

I'm working on a distributed data base. I'm trying to generate a unique ID that will serve as a *column family primary key* in [cassandra](/questions/tagged/cassandra).

I read some articles about doing this with Java using `UUID` but it seems like there is a probability for collision (even if it's very low).

I wonder if there is a way to generate a unique ID based on time maybe?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use the `TimeUUID` type in Cassandra, which backs a *Type 1 UUID*.  This uses the current time and the creator's MAC address and a sequence number. If the TimeUUID number is generated correctly this can be done with zero collisions (you can use the CQL `now()` [method](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/timeuuid_functions_r.html) or insert your own, the java SDK's provide some thread-safe implementations). The main advantage of `TimeUUIDs` is that the IDs can be time ordered. See http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/TimeBaseUUIDNotes for more info.

However, the time ordering is unlikely to be useful for row primary keys, since the ordering is useless when using a hash partitioner, though possible using a [clustering key](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/we-shall-have-order).  And also the complexity of generating a unique ID could be a source of bugs if you roll your own. Cassandra also supports *Type 4 UUIDs* by using the `UUID` type.  These are just random bits.  There is a collision probability, but the collision probability (assuming uncorrelated random number sources, which it will be if you generate in Java) is extremely low - if you created 1 billion a second for 100 years the probability of one collision is about 50%.  (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates for more details.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I use a type 1 UUID for example:   
CREATE TABLE timeline (rid uuid, PRIMARY KEY(rid))  
How would I generate the rid and Insert it into the CF ? (I read about a method called now() in Cassandra but I dunno how to use it )

Comment: You should use type timeuuid if you're using type 1 UUID.  This should work:
CREATE TABLE timeline (rid timeuuid, PRIMARY KEY(rid));
insert into timeline (rid) values (now());

Comment: I got this error: missing EOF at')'.  it's like it doesn't recognize the method now().  ps: I'm using Cassandra 1.2.0

Comment: It works for me in Cassandra 1.2.2. Possible it was fixed in some of the general CQL3 fixes. You should probably upgrade to 1.2.4 (the current latest version), there have been many fixes.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I think it's time for me to upgrade Cassandra :)

Comment: @user2090879 Perhaps you are not entering values of all of your columns. That is also a reason that you can face kind of errors.

Comment: So can I use TimeUUID  in my case where I have to generate for example over 400 000 unique ids per second to persist new rows in Cassandra database? I have to be sure that all my IDs are unique... Otherwise I will have to check somehow the uniqueness of my Ids being stored in my Cassandra

Answer (score 11):

You should investigate using [Twitter Snowflake](https://github.com/twitter/snowflake). From the project readme:

> As we at Twitter move away from Mysql towards Cassandra, we've needed a new way to generate id numbers. There is no sequential id generation facility in Cassandra, nor should there be.

Snowflake uses an intuitive algorithm that generates longs which are both time-ordered and unique. Since your database is distributed, this service should suit your needs well.

Answer (score 7):

As said by Richard you can use TimeUUID, and generating TimeUUID value is not a big deal. Just follow cassandra FAQ [timeuuid](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/FAQ#working_with_timeuuid_in_java).

Answer (score 3):

You need to use cassandra function `now()` to generate timeuuid and use `uuid()` function to generate uuid type string.