# using timeuuid as unique userid or token

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I have read some older answers, regarding generating userids. Do you know if it safe to use timeuuid as a unique identifier? I am planning on using it both for userids and for tokens.

Thanks
Regards

Comment: Its easy and safe to generate unique identifiers using timeuuid. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084573/cassandra-generate-a-unique-id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UUID and timeUUID are safe to use as unique keys. [Documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/uuid_type_r.html) on the UUID types describes them as follows:

> The UUID (universally unique id) comparator type is used to avoid
>   collisions in column names. Alternatively, you can use the timeuuid.

For more information on how UUIDs work the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) outlines the way UUIDs are generated and why they work. This question is strange since the odds of a duplicate TYPE 1 UUID is very low. From the wikipedia entry,

> ...after generating 1 billion UUIDs every second for the next 100 years,
>   the probability of creating just one duplicate would be about 50%.

This holds true for timeUUIDs.