# Sequence for the table in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, sequence

I have an usecase where I need to have a DS something like below

```
EmpName | SN
-------------
Alex    | 1

Chris   | 2
```

I just want to insert an Employee name here, SN should be auto generated serially.

How can I do this in cassandra?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create auto increment IDs in Cassandra](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935915/how-to-create-auto-increment-ids-in-cassandra)

Comment: @OrangeDog I did not get anything here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935915/how-to-create-auto-increment-ids-in-cassandra] which solves my problem.

Comment: Then your problem isn't what you think it is.

Comment: What you described exactly is not possible with Cassandra. The only thing that comes close is the counters feature, as talked about in the question mentioned by @OrangeDog

Comment: @OrangeDog I got what you are saying, But didn't want to do that way was looking for auto increment which is not possible in cassandra as per Jan Doerrenhaus

Comment: @rao the answers to the duplicate also explain that what you're asking for is impossible.

Comment: @OrangeDog Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In general you don't want to do this in a distributed environment as it requires a read before writing.

UUID's are the best way of solving this problem.  Have the client create one and insert it as the serial.

Comment: UUID at app level? I should generate there and pass on? thats what you mean?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  It should ensure you don't get conflicts.

Comment: I find this method little dicey because in distributed computing systems for ex: storm topologies may not aware of the IDs across all the workers. How can I do it there? No right?